# Firefox and IE not displaying responsive images correctly

Tags: css, responsive-design

Or who knows, maybe it's Chrome, Safari, and Opera, which all show the images how I want them, that are wrong.

Essentially what I have is an image and some associated text that I want on the side of the image when the window is big, and below the image when it is small.  The problem happens when the window is mid-range width.  The image should shrink a bit to allow room for the text (as it does in webkit/blink).  Anyway, it's probably best demonstrated in a jsfiddle:

- [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu1xebq/3/embedded/result/)
- [editor](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu1xebq/3/)

I included some Javascript in there that I use to control the height if the image is taller than the window, but I guess jsfiddle doesn't update window.height and that part works in all browsers anyway so I didn't bother debugging it.  Though I am curious if anyone has a CSS/non-javascript solution for that.

And I guess the fullscreen javascript doesn't work in jsfiddle either, so I just uploaded an [all-in-one file here](http://dangoodspeed.com/tests/test141110.html) where everything does work (besides the issue I'm writing about.

```
.mediaFile { width:auto;}
```

changing to…

```
.mediaFile { width:100%;}
```

I found changing .mediaFile width to "100%" makes Firefox show the image at the correct width most of the time, but causes other issues with fullscreen and small-height-windows that makes it more of a problem than a solution.

Comment: I don't know what the solution is, but you have a flaw in your CSS, where at exactly 48em width, both media queries are activated, so you get conflicting styles.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I assume the browser would just take whichever one was declared last.  It's not that big of a deal which styles it chooses between the two of them.